# How do I get my React Native component to respond to whether a timer is running?

Tags: react-native, timer, react-hooks

I'm having trouble getting buttons in my React Native component to change state based on whether a timer is running. I've added state to my component that I toggle when I start and stop my timer, but when I toggle this after stopping the timer, the timer continues to run (or never stops). Mysteriously (at least to this novice) if I comment out the line where the state is toggled when the timer is stops, the timer works fine.

Perhaps I'm just taking altogether the wrong approach.

How do I make my elements in my component responsive to whether my timer is currently running?

---

**SillyCounter.tsx**:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { View, Button, Text } from 'native-base'


const SillyCounter = () => {

    let timerID = 0
    const [ isRunning, updateIsRunning ] = useState(false)


    const startTimer = (): void => {
        clearInterval(timerID)
        timerID = setInterval(() => { /* ... */ }, 1000)
        updateIsRunning(true)
    }

    const stopTimer = (): void => {
        clearInterval(timerID)
        updateIsRunning(false) // Starts timer again! Comment out and timer stops as expected; why?
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        startTimer()
        return () => { stopTimer() }
    } )

    return (
        <View>
            <View style={ {flexDirection: "row"} }>
                <Button small transparent success onPress={ (): void => { startTimer() } }>
                    <Text> </Text>
                </Button>
                <Button small transparent danger onPress={ (): void => { stopTimer() } }>
                    <Text> </Text>
                </Button>
            </View>
            <Button small style={ Object.assign({},
                {backgroundColor: isRunning ? "red" : "green"} ) } >
                <Text>{isRunning ? "+" : "-"}</Text>
            </Button>
        </View>
    )

}

export default SillyCounter
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening due to `useEffect`.

Every time you change your state, `useEffect` is executed by default.

So when you click button to `stopTimer` it changes state using `updateIsRunning(false)`, as state changes your `useEffect` gets executed and in result `startTimer` executed, which will start your timer again.

When you comment `updateIsRunning(false)`, state is not getting change and `useEffect` will not execute. And finally your timer stops.

In your case you don't need `useEffect` at all. You can remove it. But in case your timer is running and you accidently navigated to some other component, you need to clean up the timer,

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => { clearInterval(timerID) }
}, [])
```

Or, if you want your timer should get start by default for first time component mounts, you need to provide second argument (empty array) to your `useEffect`,

```
useEffect(() => {
    startTimer()

    return () => { 
      // Don't call `stopTimer()` here, it will give you the warning that cannot set state on unmounted component. 
      // The `clearInterval(timerID)` will do the work, because on component re-mount it will always starts with initial values.

      clearInterval(timerID) 
    }   
}, [])  //Now useEffect executes only once when component mounts and not for sub-sequent re-renders
```

To know more about `second argument`, check out `Optimizing Performance by Skipping Effects` section from [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Comment: The only addition I would add to this is you won't want to remove `useEffect` entirely - if the timer is running when the component is unmounted it needs to be cleaned up. So if you don't want the timer to start on component mount you still want `useEffect(() => (() => clearInterval(timerId)))` to clean up any running timer when the component unmounts.

Comment: @azundo, You are correct. Upadated the answer with some minor corrections.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work for me, but now I'm having what I think is an [unrelated problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57546402/656912), but I'm getting [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57546443/656912) that seem to collide with this answer.