# How do I clear a timer using in my React component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, timer, react-hooks

I'm having trouble figuring out why my counter won't reset when I attempt to reset it from a control. I suspect that that I'm making some kind of novice (common and not embarrassing) mistake in how I manipulate state from within my controls.

For example, if I clock "Faster" several times and then click "Normal" counting continues at an accelerated pace: apparently the faster timer has not been cleared by the invocation of `startTimer`. Only by subsequently clicking "Reset", or "Stop" followed by "Start" does the faster timer appear to clear. But I'm mystified by why this should be the case: all paths use `clearInterval` in the same way.

I suspect that I'm not grasping something general about how state is manipulated in a component; or perhaps how to correctly access a timer from component state.

Why can't I get my timer to clear as expected?

**WobblyCounter.tsx**:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View, Button, Text } from 'native-base'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const WobblyCounter = () => {

    const [ timerID, setTimerID ] = useState(0)
    const [ isRunning, updateIsRunning ] = useState(false)
    const [ interval, updateInterval ] = useState(1000)

    const count = useSelector((state) => state.count)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const startTimer = (): void => {
        clearInterval(timerID)
        setTimerID(setInterval(() => { dispatch( {type: "INCREMENT", step: 1} ) }, interval))
        updateIsRunning(true)
    }

    const stopTimer = (): void => {
        clearInterval(timerID)
        updateIsRunning(false)
    }

    return (
        <View style={ {paddingTop:50} }>
            <Button
                onPress={ (): void => { dispatch( {type: "RESET"} ); startTimer() } }>
                <Text>Reset</Text>
            </Button>
            <View style={ {flexDirection: "row"} }>
                <Button small bordered dark disabled={ interval <= 250 }
                    onPress={ (): void => { updateInterval(Math.max(interval - 250, 250)); startTimer() } }>
                    <Text>Faster</Text>
                </Button>
                <Button small bordered dark disabled={ interval == 1000 }
                    onPress={ (): void => { updateInterval(1000); startTimer() } }>
                    <Text>Normal</Text>
                </Button>
                <Button small bordered dark
                    onPress={ (): void => { updateInterval(interval + 250); startTimer() } }>
                    <Text>Slower</Text>
                </Button>
            </View>
            <Button small style={ Object.assign( {}, {backgroundColor: isRunning ? "red" : "green"} ) }
                onPress={ (): void => { isRunning ? stopTimer() : startTimer() } }>
                <Text>{isRunning ? "Stop" : "Start"}</Text>
            </Button>
            <Text>
                Debug{"\n"}count = {count}{"\n"}interval = {interval}{"\n"}timerID = {timerID}
            </Text>
        </View>
    )

}

export default WobblyCounter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that the closure `startTimer` is using old state value :

1. on first render timerID=0 and interval=1000, `startTimer` is created with these values.
2. when you click on "Faster", `updateInterval` is called and the interval state is changed to 750 but the component isn't rendered yet, and so `startTimer` is called with the old value interval=1000.
3. The component re-render timerID=1 and interval=750, `startTimer` is re-created with these values.
4. when you click on "Normal", `updateInterval` is called and the interval state is changed to 1000 but the component isn't rendered yet, `startTimer` is called with the old value interval=750. That is why the counter is still running fast.

One way to fix this problem is to use a custom hook `useInterval` [proposed here by Dan Abramov](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/#just-show-me-the-code), and only update the relevant state (interval, isRunning) when the buttons are clicked.

```
  useInterval(
     () => {
         dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT", step: 1 });
     },
     isRunning ? interval : null
  );
```

You can find the completed code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-williams-tplep?fontsize=14) (I removed react-native)

Comment: In fact, having `timerID`, `isRunning`, and `interval` as state probably isn't even the right way to go. Putting them in the store makes things a lot simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You reset the timer via [**cleanup callback**](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) of `useEffect` with [an empty dep array](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).

Which means this side effect will **run once on the component** unmount:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // startTimer will run once on component mount
  startTimer();

  // The cleanup callback will run once on component unmount
  return stopTimer;
}, []);
```

But, in your case, you never unmount the component (because you dispatch actions on button clicks, that mean you always at update cycle), try put a breakpoint at `stopTimer`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad: I should have simplified the example more. I've cut out `useEffect` in the example, but the issue remains.

Comment: There are too many issues in your code, you should put a sandbox. The main problem that I notice it is using an immutable state and not reference to keep up with the "right" value of the counter.

Comment: Could you be more specific about hat many issues you see? It looks to me like state is all handled correctly except for the timer ID, which appears to have some unique properties that don't allow it to be treated like normal "state".

Comment: like when you dispatch + startTimer, there are more than 3 renders happen in unknown time (maybe there will be batch), and you expect them to be in some order like: reset => useSelector => start count

Comment: Ah, OK so there is something fundamental about React that I've not grasped then. It sounds like breaking down what happens when I click "Reset" vs what happens when I click, say, "Normal" will shed a lot of light and be an answer to this question.

Comment: I'd assumed that the code was doing what it looked like it was doing: first updating the interval state (no side effects) and then using that state to clear the current timer and start a new one. But (much) more appears to be going on.

Comment: As I said, an example to play with is much easier to find the problem, making one, not in react-native is straight forward too. https://codesandbox.io

Comment: Can't get [the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-darkness-yfvso) to work: _"Something went wrong while packaging the dependency react-native@0.60.5: Command failed"_.

Comment: FWIW, I can "fix" the issue by not having `interval` as a prop but just as a variable and using `const updateInterval = (x) => {interval = x}`. That's doesn't make anything more clear to me though. (Trying the same with the timerID makes no difference.)